# Keras custom metrics and set threshold to do this

Tags: python, keras

I would like to do Rainfall-prediction,and i have the ground truth like

`y_true =  [14.0,0.5,0.3,0,0,0.25,2.0,1.5]` and the `y_pred = [2.0,0,1.0,1.5,0,0,0,0]`.

Now,I want to set a `threshold = 0.5`, so `y_true =  [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]`, `y_pred = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]`
and define two custom metrics `FAR` and `POD`, and defined as following

`FAR = falsealarms/(hits+falsealarms)` and `POD= hits/(hits+misses)`, where hits (`prediction = 1`, `truth = 1`),
misses (`prediction = 0`, `truth = 1`) and false alarms (`prediction = 1`, `truth = 0`)

How to set threshold like this example and implement `FAR` and `POD` in Keras backend?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post what you have done so far, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Are you using tensorflow? You can use a tensorflow conditional